# Trigger button animation on event in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, animation

I'm trying to use the `$animate` service in a custom directive. I'm running into an issue where the `$animate` service is not applying the specified class immediately (likely an issue with `$apply`'s timing), nor does the first animation complete before `$animate` removes the class.

I want:

- `mousedown` to always start the animation
- the animation to always finish
- the animation to 'hold' for extended `mousedown` events
- the animation to end immediately after **both** finishing the animation **and** `mouseup` have occurred.

In other words I *never* want the animation to jump. I'd prefer to use `$animate`, but at this point I'm willing to try other solutions…

**Please do not use jQuery in your solution.**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('onActivate', function($parse, $q, $animate, $timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var hasTouch = false;
        var handler = $parse(attr.onActivate);

        element.one('mousedown', function() {
          if (!hasTouch) {
            console.log('Clicked!');
            scope.$apply(function() {
              $animate.addClass(element, 'pressed');
            });

            element.on('mousedown', function() {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                $animate.addClass(element, 'pressed');
              });
            });
            element.on('mouseup', function() {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                $animate.removeClass(element, 'pressed');
              });
            });
            element.on('click', function(event) {
              scope.$evalAsync(handler(scope, {
                $event: event
              }));
            });
          }
        });
        element.one('touchstart', function(event) {
          hasTouch = true;

          $animate.addClass(element, 'pressed');
          
          element.on('touchstart', function() {
            $animate.addClass(element, 'pressed');
          });
          element.on('touchend touchcancel', function() {
            $animate.removeClass(element, 'pressed');
          });
          
          element.on('touchend', function(event) {
            scope.$evalAsync(handler(scope, {
              $event: event
            }));
          });
        });
      }
    }
  })
```

```css
/* Vendor prefixes are handled automatically
   by prefixfree */

@keyframes grow {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(0.75);
  }
}

button {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 2rem;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
button.pressed {
  transition: none;
  animation: grow 1s ease;
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

button:not(.pressed) {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <button on-activate=""> Click Me </button>
  <p style="font-family: sans-serif;">The animation jumps unless the user holds the button down. I want the <code>.pressed</code> animation to finish regardless of how long the users holds the button down.</p>
</body>
```